# Using MySQL variables with PDO Select statements

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a series of MySql queries that need to be called with PDO. Many of them are using MySql variables. Surely, a solution would be to use PDO prepared statements but that's not always the case. `Insert` and `Update` statements are running with no problems but `Select` is throwing an error.
(I'm unable to paste it for you right now. Please say if it's necessary)

Select queries are running fine when executed in MySQL Workbench.

```
SET 
    @CY = YEAR(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL -17 DAY));

SELECT
   *
FROM
    TableX
WHERE
    TableX.Year IN (@CY, @CY-1)
```

Any ideas?

Additional info: `PHP 5.3.29` and `MYSQL 5.5.47`

Comment: What error is the SELECT throwing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may execute similar queries with two steps:

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SET @CY = YEAR(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE,INTERVAL -17 DAY));');
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT @CY, @CY-1');
$data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($data);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [@CY] => 2016
            [@CY-1] => 2015
        )

)
```